# 4G internet with Huawei E220 or K5150

Tags: networking, hardware, driver

I have got a Huawei E220 modem and I connect it with `sakis3g`. Recently I switched to a 4G network with 40Mb/s speed.

However, with this modem I still get only 2Mb/s, because I think I connect through 3G. I suppose that this model simply doesn't support 4G.

I can get a Vodafone K5150 modem, but I'm not sure about the drivers for RPi. I have found the information that "the product carries the linux drivers", but I'm not sure how much are the drivers unversal for all distros.

So the question: Can I use K5150 modem easily with RPi? And can I use `sakis3g` for connecting to a 4G network?

Comment: It seems to be possible. Have you read [this topic at the official Raspberry Pi forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=38112&p=360455)?

Comment: @M.Mimpen Now I went through it very briefly (which is the only thing that can be done since forums are so bad in information structure). Well, I decided to simply get the Vodafone dongle (it cost EUR 3 and 1 hour in the ISP's office), I'll see later if it works well. They provide an automatic configurator for linux which works on my Fedora 12.

Comment: It would have been nice if you tried it out and could form an answer on this Exchange for future users... :)

Comment: @M.Mimpen I plan to do that if I succeed (disclaimer: I have ~30k SE rep so I know well how the sites work `;)` )

Comment: @M.Mimpen I reduced the problem into a problem of running `x86` binaries on RPi `:-/`

Comment: I hate those pragmatic solutions! You better spend 5 hours of tweaking to make it work out of the box :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13576/discussion-between-tohecz-and-m-mimpen)

Comment: @yo' Were you able to get the K5150 to work?